# Difference between %RANDOM% and Math.random() in terms of randomness

Tags: batch-file, random, jscript, wsh

I have a hybrid batch/jscript file (using `cscript`) that has to randomly pick a quote from a text file. So, I need some RNG to call that is sufficiently random for results to not be too repeating between sessions to notice.

We all know `%RANDOM%` isn't that great, but I've noticed that executing `%RANDOM%` multiple times in a row (in the same session) gives a more satisfying number of results.

Is this true or am I better off using the below JScript?

```
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

WScript.echo(getRandomNumber(0, 32767));
```

If there **is** a significant *statistical* difference between calling `%RANDOM%` twice vs. calling the `getRandomNumber` function once, I'm all ears.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators

Comment: Hmm, that's a lot of (P)RNG material. Perhaps i'm not looking for the technical in-depth (background) stuff, but i'm looking for a more straightforward/simple answer on the above situation? - For instance: How much more random is the number obtained after doing %RANDOM% a second time in a row?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are talking about batch script (bat file), then about JavaScript. By the way the purpose you want to use the generator for doesn't seem to need so much high quality of statistical randomness and maybe `%RANDOM%` is just enough.

Comment: Oops, i'm sorry for not having mentioned it. I'm using a hybrid batch/jscript file with cscript. And no, %RANDOM% is too predictable for this (that's why i exec. it twice in a row). I'm only interested in the statistical differences between running %RANDOM% twice vs. calling getRandomNumber function once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's built-in random number generator varies with the engine implementation. It's hard to say anything about it without knowing the underlying generator. The same is true for `%RANDOM%` - however it is probably implemented as a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG). Searching on the web you can easily find [forum posts about `%RANDOM%`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100617-00/?p=13673), which also suggests it is implemented as a LCG which - in general - has notoriously bad statistical properties.

Now the question is whether `Math.random()` performs better or not? It could also be implemented as an LCG, newer implementations (like Google V8, Microsoft Edge) however implement it as a variant of [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift). If you know the JavaScript engine you use, you can easily find out the type of the generator so you can also find information about its statistical quality.

As a gold standard, you can also compare the two generators in heavy statistical test suites like [Diehard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) and [TestU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01), which - I think - would be an overkill for your purpose.

As a final advice, if I had to choose between the two without knowing them, I would go with the JavaScript generator. If it is implemented as an LCG, then it is probably not really worse than `%RANDOM%`,
otherwise it is better.

But hey, you don't have to choose between two potentially bad generators: use a custom one! Check [this page](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/) for simple, modern, high quality generators you can port to JavaScript.

Comment: My oh my, the plasmacel has spoken (and in what way!). I believe you are the most evolved plasmacel to be found on SO. I'm in awe of the quality/level of your answer. - On a more serious note: Thank you very much for the effort. Much appreciated! :-)